# PHP form not receiving email

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to add a php form that sends a message with a name and email of the one who sent it, this is my current html, btw i use bootstrap:

```
    <div class="row" id="contact-padding">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="contact-form1">
            <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                <p></p><br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Име" id="formInput">
                <p></p><br><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Поща"  id="formInput">
                <p></p><br><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" id="formInput">

                <p></p><br>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25" placeholder="Запишете съобщението, което искате да изпратите." ></textarea><br/><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Изпрати" id="send">
                    <input type="reset" value="Изчисти" id="send">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the PHP script that i use for this html:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "zombaza@abv.bg";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Everytime i try to send the message, it just opens the php file on a new page and i dont receive the email on "zombaza@abv.bg"

I've tried a couple of things but they dont seem to work and it is really important that i finish this job so if somebody has an idea, please share it with me, i would be really thankful!

Comment: So what output you receive? Error or Thank you?

Comment: One question because the last sentence does it not make very clear: Does the host/computer you run this on have PHP installed? Do you just get your PHP code back after submitting?

Comment: if you're trying in localhost is normal.

Comment: I am using localhost yes, so i need to be in a domain in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Sending mail is notoriously open to SPAM. In your case, you're allowing unvalidated content to go directly into an email header: that's asking for trouble. You also need to be careful with white space and newlines.

To help project yourself, go for a trusted mail script/class/library. I regularly use swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) as it has suitable configuration, error trapping and so on.

If you need to fix your own code above, add in standard debugging (Check error_reporting and ini_set('display_errors') ) as they will reveal issues in the code. Put an "echo" at the top so you know you're calling the right script etc (the "open in a new page" actually suggests you have some JavaScript that's interfering - disable JS functions if that's the case).

But always check your inputs before outputting into email, databases or HTML pages.

Answer (score -1):

add @ in this

```
  @mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

Comment: @ supresses all warnings/errors its not good to use it, but at least give it a try

Comment: Did and no change, i didnt receive a mail and it still loaded that php file i have on a new page

Comment: did you check your local php server if it allows sending mail locally? if not it wont send.

Comment: how do i allow that sending?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost   check this hope it helps you

Comment: the post that katyoshah sent didnt work, just tested it when got home :/